# Laravel divide in controller and show in blade

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My script works fine, but showing not right. Example with this code i having 5 people with most have damage by %.

```
$user->bestaimers = DB::table('csstats AS cs')
>leftJoin('users AS u', DB::raw('BINARY u.steam_id'), '=', DB::raw('BINARY cs.steamid'))
->select("cs.*", "u.*")
->orderBy('cs.h_1', 'desc')->orderBy('hits', 'desc')
->take(5)
->get('');
```

And my view:

```
    @foreach ($user->bestaimers as $bestaimer)
<?php echo number_format($bestaimer->h_1 / $bestaimer->hits * 100,2); ?>%
    @endforeach
```

But tis showing first player who have most allhits. I need to order by **$bestaimer->h_1 / $bestaimer->hits * 100,2**

Any help?

Comment: If the amount of data allows to first fetch all it may be easier and better to read to order it in PHP/Laravel using the collection: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-sortbydesc

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to select this $bestaimer->h_1 / $bestaimer->hits * 100,2 in sql and then order by this value?

Something like this:

`SELECT cs.*, u.*, (ROUND(cs.h_1/hits*100,2)) as val FROM csstats as cs
LEFT JOIN users as u ON u.steam_id = cs.steamid
ORDER BY val DESC
LIMIT 5`